# Inserir Valores em Array Python

Tags: python, array, input, float, map

A questão é que os valores de `bb`,`cc`,`dd` **não** estão sendo inseridos nos vetores `vx`,`vy`,`vz`.

```py
vr=vx=vy=vz=[]
N=aa=bb=cc=dd=0
N=int(input())
for i in range(N):
    aa,bb,cc,dd=map(float, input().split())
    vr.append(aa)
    vx.append(bb)
    vy.append(cc)
    vz.append(dd)
    print(aa,bb,cc,dd)
    print(vr[i],vx[i],vy[i],vz[i])
```

Comment: O que esse código deveria fazer? Qual é a entrada e qual é a saída produzida?

Comment: Você entende que `vr`, `vx`, `vy` e `vz` são a mesma lista certo? Não são 4 listas diferentes.

Comment: hmmmm, vlw! mano, muito obrigado! não tinha pensado nisso.

Comment: Que confuso esse código.

Comment: não sei qual a sua fnalidade com isso, nem quem vai usar iu pra que, mas colcoar `input("Digite quatro números separados por espaço: ")`  em vez de só `input()` com certeza facilita a vida de quem for rodar esse programa - mesmo que seja só você.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu simplesmente mudei sua inicialização para separar os arrays (como você colocou, eles eram a mesma coisa) e retirei a linha de inicialização das variáveis, pois não parecem ser necessárias. Veja se faz o que você queria.

```
vr=[]
vx=[]
vy=[]
vz=[]
N=int(input())
for i in range(N):
    aa,bb,cc,dd=map(float, input().split())
    vr.append(aa)
    vx.append(bb)
    vy.append(cc)
    vz.append(dd)
    print(aa,bb,cc,dd)
    print(vr[i],vx[i],vy[i],vz[i])
```